# How do I get pending windows updates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am trying to get pending windows updates on python but no module returns me the pending windows updates, only windows update history, I don't need especifiation about the update I just need to know if there are pending updates or not, I'm trying to use this code:

```
from windows_tools.updates import get_windows_updates
import os

for update in get_windows_updates(filter_duplicates=True, include_all_states=False):
    print(update)
```

It returns:

```
    {'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:18:21', 'title': '9PLFNLNT3G5G-AppUp.IntelGraphicsExperience', 'description': '9PLFNLNT3G5G-1152921505694231446', 'supporturl': '', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:18:21', 'title': '9NBLGGH3FRZM-Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00', 'description': '9NBLGGH3FRZM-1152921505694106457', 'supporturl': '', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:18:21', 'title': '9MW2LKJ0TPJF-Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2', 'description': '9MW2LKJ0TPJF-1152921505692414645', 'supporturl': '', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:18:21', 'title': '9PLL735RFDSM-Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2', 'description': '9PLL735RFDSM-1152921505689378154', 'supporturl': '', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:18:15', 'title': 'HP Inc. - HIDClass - 2.1.16.30156', 'description': 'HP Inc. HIDClass  driver update released in  November 2021', 'supporturl': 'http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=hub', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:18:03', 'title': 'Intel Corporation - Bluetooth - 20.100.7.1', 'description': 'Intel Corporation Bluetooth  driver update released in  July 2020', 'supporturl': 'http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=hub', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:18:01', 'title': 'Intel Corporation - Extension - 12/16/2018 12:00:00 AM - 20.110.1.1', 'description': 'Intel Corporation Extension  driver update released in  December 2018', 'supporturl': 'http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=hub', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:17:50', 'title': 'Intel Corporation - Display - 27.20.100.8681', 'description': 'Intel Corporation Display  driver update released in  September 2020', 'supporturl': 'http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=hub', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': None, 'date': '2022-01-14 20:15:12', 'title': 'Realtek Semiconductor Corp. - MEDIA - 6.0.8940.1', 'description': 'Realtek Semiconductor Corp. MEDIA  driver update released in  April 2020', 'supporturl': 'http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=hub', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': 'KB4591272', 'date': '2022-01-14 20:13:19', 'title': '2021-11 Atualização do Windows 10 Version 21H2 para sistemas baseados em x64 (KB4591272)', 'description': 'Instale esta atualização para resolver problemas no Windows. Para obter a lista completa dos problemas incluídos nesta atualização, consulte o artigo da Base de Dados de Conhecimento Microsoft associado. Talvez seja necessário reiniciar o computador após instalar este item.', 'supporturl': 'http://support.microsoft.com', 'operation': 'installation', 'result': 'succeeded'}
{'kb': 'KB5003791', 'date': '2021-10-06 00:00:00', 'title': None, 'description': 'Update', 'supporturl': 'https://support.microsoft.com/help/5003791', 'operation': None, 'result': None}
{'kb': 'KB5009636', 'date': '2022-01-20 00:00:00', 'title': None, 'description': 'Update', 'supporturl': None, 'operation': None, 'result': None}
{'kb': 'KB5005699', 'date': '2021-10-06 00:00:00', 'title': None, 'description': 'Security Update', 'supporturl': None, 'operation': None, 'result': None}
```

I get all my installed updates and not the pending ones, how can I find the pending ones programmatically.

I'm using python 3.10

Comment: Does setting `include_all_states` to `True` lists you the pending ones ?

Comment: No, it does not, my solution was to create a vbs script to create a txt file with the number of pending updates and then work with the txt in python

Answer (score 0):

There was no solution in python, so I did a vbs script and called from inside my function.
the vbs script is

```
Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateupdateSearcher()        
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")


If searchResult.Updates.Count <> 0 Then 

For i = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count - 1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(i)
    
Next
End If

Main

Sub Main()
    Dim result, fso, fs
    result = 1 / Cos(25)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fs  = fso.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)
    fs.Write searchResult.Updates.Count
    fs.Close
End Sub
```

It gets the number of pending updates, then I called inside my function like this

```
import subprocess, time, os


class update_monitor():
    def __init__(self):
        self.output='output.txt'
    
    def updates_restando(self):
        os.system(r'script.vbs')

        time.sleep(10)

        with open(self.output,'r') as file:
            for i in file:
                if i == '0':
                    print('Não há atualizações disponiveis')
                    return 'Não há atualizações disponiveis'
                else:
                    print('Existem atualizações pendentes')
                    return 'Existem atualizações pendentes'


a = update_monitor()
a.updates_restando()
```

this solution worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client

class WindowsUpdateChecker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.update_session = win32com.client.Dispatch('Microsoft.Update.Session')

    def get_pending_updates(self):
        search_result = self.update_session.CreateUpdateSearcher().Search('IsInstalled=0')
        updates = search_result.Updates

        pending_updates = []
        for update in updates:
            pending_updates.append({
                'Title': update.Title,
                'Description': update.Description,
                'KB': update.KBArticleIDs[0] if update.KBArticleIDs else 'N/A'
            })

        return pending_updates

if __name__ == "__main__":
    checker = WindowsUpdateChecker()
    pending_updates = checker.get_pending_updates()

    if pending_updates:
        print("Pending Windows Updates:")
        for update in pending_updates:
            print(f"Title: {update['Title']}")
            print(f"Description: {update['Description']}")
            print(f"KB Article: {update['KB']}")
            print("=" * 30)
    else:
        print("No pending updates.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).